# Set observer to object change

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am searching for a way where i am can create a method, which called only when any changes applies on Object

**For Example** let's take a label. i am changing text of this label in different cases. Now what i need i created one method:

```
- (void)labelTextChangeNotification {

}
```

It will call every time when my label text will change
i can use NSNotification for getting this. for `NSNotification` we need to Post Notification.
My requirement is like Observer which observe my label text change. 
is there any way to get this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using key-value observing (KVO):

```
[label addObserver:self
    forKeyPath:@"text"
       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
             | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
       context:NULL];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    /* etc. */
}
}
```

When you change value of label this observervalue method  will be called. 
Also in the change Dictionary you will find all the detail.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**In order to receive key-value observing notifications for a property, three things are required:**

1. The observed class must be key-value observing compliant for the
   property that you wish to observe.
2. You must register the observing object with the observed object,
   using the method `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`.
3. The observing class must implement
   `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`.

> In order to be notified of changes to a property, an observing object
>   must first register with the object to be observed by sending it an
>   `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` message, passing the observer
>   object and the key path of the property to be observed. The options
>   parameter specifies the information that is provided to the observer
>   when a change notification is sent. Using the option
>   `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` specifies that the original object value
>   is provided to the observer as an entry in the change dictionary.
>   Specifying the `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` option provides the new
>   value as an entry in the change dictionary. To receive both values,
>   you would bitwise OR the option constants

Referred from Apple doc

So, you can use **KVO**  when the text changes of `UILabel`:-

```
[labelName addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

This method will notify whenever the label text changes:-

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSLog(@"the text has been changed");
}
```